# Navigation toolbar hides when application is restarted

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a navigation based app where one of the views shows a toolbar.  If I press the Home key and reenter the application the toolbar hides itself.  I tried to unhide in viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear, but they never fire.

Where is the proper place to unhide the toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ViewDidAppear/ViewWillAppear wont get called when an application enters foreground. To handle application entered foreground, you need to create a notification.

In Appdelegate add following code to applicationWillEnterForeground:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:       @"UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification" object: nil];
}
```

Then In your respective view controller do following changes

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnterForeground:)
                                             name:  @"UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification"
                                           object: nil];
}

- (void) handleEnterForeground: (NSNotification*) sender
{
    //Do whatever you need to do to handle the enter foreground notification
}
```